# Trigger in Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, triggers

What is the most efficient way to create this trigger in Postgres.

I'll present below a very simplified example to what I need for my purposes, but it is based on the same concept.

Consider, we have got the schema defined below:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  item_id int4,
  part_no int4,
  description text);

CREATE TABLE blacklist (
  part_no int4,
  reason text);

CREATE TABLE matches (
  item_id int4,
  part_no int4,
  reason text);
```

Then, every time a new item is added, we check if it is on the blacklist (comparing the part_no), and if it is, we create a new entry on the matches table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want a before-insert or after-insert [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) on `items`:

```
create trigger blacklist_matches after insert on items
for each row execute procedure check_blacklist();
```

Then the `check_blacklist` function would look something like this:

```
create function check_blacklist()
    returns trigger as $$
begin
    insert into matches (item_id, part_no, reason)
    select NEW.item_id, NEW.part_no, blacklist.reason
    from blacklist
    where blacklist.part_no = NEW.part_no;
    return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The funny looking `$$` is, more or less, the SQL version of a heredoc.

That wraps the "is it on the blacklist" check and the `matches` insertion in one simple bit of SQL. The [`NEW` variable in a trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) is a reference to the new row that you're working with. If `NEW.part_no` doesn't match anything in `blacklist`, then the SELECT won't produce anything and the INSERT will not be executed.

Presumably you'd have an index on `blacklist.part_no` (which looks like a PK anyway) so the above should be quick enough.

The PostgreSQL documentation is pretty good and has a whole section on [stored procedures and triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) if you need a reference.

Comment: thanx, but could you also please explain the syntax for creating the function?